# merge multiple parquet files in different folders in ADLS through ADX

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have parquet files per item in ADLS sitting under each of subfolders named the same as the item name.
The folder structure is like this,
"abfss://storage_name@container_name.dfs.core.windows.net/UserData/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/"

under this path, I have subfolders named: 'applev1','bananav2','grapev3','orangev1','applev2' ( but there are some other folders named differently)
ex) "abfss://storage_name@container_name.dfs.core.windows.net/UserData/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/applev2/"

and under each of these folders, I have parquet files with the same schema.

what I want to do is to merge the parquet files under each of these folders(applev1,bananav2) into one dataframe.

I know I can read parquet files in ADX from ADX like this..

```
.create external table sample_table (column1: string,column2: string,column3:string
 )
kind = storage
dataformat = parquet('abfss://storage_name@container_name.dfs.core.windows.net/UserData/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/applev2/')
```

but I need to merge all the parquet files per item(applev1,bananav2,grapev3) into one table..

How can I do this in ADX?
anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

You can create mapping, add the [SourceLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/mappings#mapping-transformations) property and then filter on it.

It looks something like this (no need to define the rest of the columns):

````
.create-or-alter external table MyExtTab mapping "MyExtTabMap" 
```
[
    {"Column": "Path"   ,"Properties": {"Transform": "SourceLocation"}}
]
```
````

---

Seems straight forward.

An ADX external table supports -

1. multiple locations
2. root folder (scans recursively all files under that folder)

```
.create-or-alter external table MyExtTab(<schema>)
kind=storage  
dataformat=parquet
(   
    h"https://<storageAccountName1>.blob.core.windows.net/<containerName1>/path1/to1/root1/folder1;<secret1>"
   ,h"https://<storageAccountName2>.blob.core.windows.net/<containerName2>/path2/to2/root2/folder2;<secret2>"
)
```

Comment: hi, @David דודו Markovitz, thank you so much for your answer! as we have new sub-folders added per item every week, is there anyway to interate through the folder names in ADX and read the files?

Comment: Those sub-folders, are still under the same root folder, aren't they?

Comment: Hi @David דודו Markovitz, yes they are but there are a few other sub-folders not related to the items. So what I need to do is to filter out the folder name that ends with "v1,v2,v3"and iterate through them..

Comment: See updated answer (and consider your folders structure)

Comment: Thanks @David דודו Markovitz! I just wonder if you could add a bit of explanation how to do it as I'm really new to this..(I went through the doc but still not sure how to do it, maybe Im dumb..) would really appreciate your help!